# Dropbox chooser with Oauth

Tags: ios, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on integrating dropbox with iOS application.  I want to implement below functionality.

- User can share his existing dropbox file with app.
- If user modifies any of the files, i should able to fetch the updated file and notify app server.
- Also these files are not app related ones. User can share any docs in his dropbox account with app

After going through API, i found that i can use dropbox chooser UI to share files. chooser is generating temporary URL which i can share with my server to extract the file from dropbox.

But to get the modified files, i have to integrate with OAuth permission to run delta query on dropbox account. Here i am struck with two parallel functionalities chooser and OAuth which seems not related to each other. Even while asking OAuth permission also, dropbox taking to web url to grant permission instead of showing already logged in user on iOS.

How do i verify both chooser account and OAuth granted account are same? How will i show dropbox chooser(of OAuth connected) when user wants to add any file to app?

Correct me if i am wrong in understanding dropbox API. Also let me know if i have to provide more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to use the Chooser and OAuth-based Dropbox APIs together, but I've recorded this as a feature request.

Comment: What is the alternative way of providing chooser for selecting files using OAuth? Should i write my own implementation to fetch all docs of each folder build ui similar to Chooser?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly build your own file selecting UI using the Core API, for example. You can use /delta to load up the entire server-state: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta or /metadata for loading individual folder levels: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata